# Logging in: drop-down list shows old addresses, old passwords. Always have to change them

Tags: gmail

I have several gmail accounts for different purposes. When logging in to access any of my accounts, the drop-down list that appears on the sign-on page comes up with six accounts. A couple of them are correct and when clicked on take me to the correct account. But there are two others that I have to manually change in order to access those accounts. Also, the passwords associated with those accounts are old passwords and I always have to type in the more recent password. How do I update the drop-down list of email addresses and the related disguised passwords that appear? Also on that list is an account I do not use any more and would like to have it removed from the list. How can I make these changes?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a web browser feature.

Answer (score 1):

Its simple, just hover over the option in the drop down you want to remove, then click `delete` on your keyboard, that's it, it will never show up again.

To update your password, try to delete the option as i told you, then the next time you will log in to gmail, it might save your new one only...